# Nodejs Printing to Non standard output

Tags: node.js, redirect, file-descriptor, output-redirect

node 5.4.1
windows 10

```
//program.js
console.log("hello world");
```

What i want to achieve is node program.js 3>file.txt

```
//file.txt
hello world
```

I have tried:

```
fs.createWriteStream(null,{fd:3})
//creates error bad file descriptor

fs.openSync(null,{fd:3})
//Another error


var tty = require("tty");
var out = new tty.WriteStream(3);
//Empty print
```

I don't know what else to try. Any advice.

What is the 3 in 3>file.

I don't even know the term to search using. 
I have used:

File Descriptor

Non Standard Output

Output 3

If my question doesn't define clearly what i want please comment so i can correct where i have went wrong.

I have attempted to define:

What i want.

What i have tried.

Where I have look.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: `fs.createWriteStream(null, { fd : 3 })` works just fine for me, provided (obviously) that the output is redirected using `3>file.txt` (otherwise you _will_ get a "bad file descriptor" error, but that's to be expected).

Comment: my platform is windows. Could this be the reason? what are you using

Comment: also are you using the write function on the created stream?

Comment: I get bad file descriptor if i do 3>file.txt or 3>&1 or without anything

Comment: I'm using OSX, which is a UNIX so that might have something to do with why it's working for me. And yes, I'm using `write` on the stream.

Comment: alright i am tempted to say this is only a problem on windows. When i use 2 for the fd it prints correctly, but any other number than 1,2 results in an error.

Answer (score 1):

This program should do what you need:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.createWriteStream(null, {fd: 3});
stream.write("OK\n");
```

If run without proper redirection, it gives the "EBADF: bad file descriptor" error:

```
$ node fd3.js
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, write
    at Error (native)
```

When run with a redirection of FD 3, it prints OK:

```
$ node fd3.js 3>&1
OK
```

If it doesn't work on Windows then maybe it's a bug in Node or the `fs` module and you should report it or see if it was reported already:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues

You didn't actually show **what errors do you get** so it's really hard to answer your question in any more detail.

### Update

As I wrote in the comments it would be very helpful to see what exact error message is printed to have some idea if it is a bug in Node or in the fs module or maybe a problem with bad invocation, or error in the program - in your question you show how you open the streams but you don't show how you actually attempt to print anything.

For example, I can run my example programs in those two ways:

```
node fd3.js 2>&1
```

or:

```
node fd3.js 3>&4
```

In both cases I can say that I get a "bad file descriptor" error but both of those errors are actually different errors, on different descriptors, reported by different subsystems during different steps in the invocation.

After reading here that it's a problem with Windows that may not even have a concept of file descriptors higher than 2, I've done some experiments by running this bat file on Windows 10:

```
@echo off
echo abc 1>&3
```

And it works just fine. When I invoke it as:

```
winfdtest 3>file.txt
```

I get `abc` written in `file.txt`. In fact, I don't even get a bad descriptor error when I don't redirect fd 3 to a file, in which case it gets printed to the console and no errors are shown. On the other hand when I run it as:

```
winfdtest 4>file.txt
```

the `abc` gets printed to the console and the `file.txt` is empty so it means that the correct descriptor gets redirected, and those that are not redirected get printed to the console.

My conclusion is that the same should work in Node and if it doesn't then it's a bug. Unfortunately no exact code and no exact error messages was shown in the question so it's hard to say what is going wrong exactly.

Comment: The error the OP is getting is "bad file descriptor" (stated in the question).

Comment: @robertklep I know but I'd like to see exactly what is printed to have some idea of it is a bug in Node or in the fs module. For example, when I run my example as `node fd3.js 2>&1` I get a "bad file descriptor" error and when I run it as `node fd3.js 3>&4` I get a "bad file descriptor" error - but in both cases those are different descriptors, different errors and reported by different sybsystems. In some cases just a vague notion of an error with no proper context is not enough to diagnose the problem especially when I don't know if it's a Node bug a or for example a bad program invocation.

Comment: fair enough, although we came to the conclusion that it's an issue that has to do with the code running on Windows, which most likely does not have a similar I/O setup as UNIX and where "file descriptor 3" may not even mean anything (although I have zero knowledge about how Windows works in that regard). But you're right, having the specific error messages may yield a clue.

Comment: @robertklep I just tested in on Windows and you can definitely echo in a bat file to descriptor 3 and then redirect it to a file when run from the cmd prompt. So file descriptor 3 definitely means something, the redirection works in bat files and should work for Node programs as well. I'm not a Windows expert myself but I've done some experiments - see my updated answer.

Comment: yeah, I would _assume_ that the Node program should work as well. Thanks for testing :-)

Comment: The error message i got is exactly the one that you are printing above. I am pretty sure i am doing my redirects correctly because you can use 1 or 2 which is stdout and stderr and they both work correctly, however if i use 3 then i get the error of bad file descriptor. My redirect is done the way that you have stated. I will create a repo and test on a linux machine to see if i get different result on a linux box.

Comment: i could copy paste the code you have if would make it clearer but it's the exact same error, and i wouldn't do {fd:3}  and then try to redirect to some other random number. I appreciate you being thoural however.

I am somewhat knowledgeable   when i used {fd:3}  i tried redirecting with this node.exe program.js 3>&1